# jQuery UI DatePicker month and year in one dropdown

Tags: jquery, datepicker, customization

Is there a way to combine month and year dropdown elements in one dropdown.
The new dropdown should contain elements like '04/2014', '05/2014' and so on up to max date.

Comment: Here is a "not-working" demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afLjk/71/

Answer (score 0):

It's a hacky approach, but you could do this:

Set `changeYear` and `changeMonth` to false. Add a delegated click listener to the body.

```
$('body').on('click', '#ui-datepicker-title', function() { ... });
```

Where the body of the function would get the current year/month, populate a custom div with the required values and position the div over the datepicker's header.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my question is on customizing/extending the existing jquery datepicker not displaying a default datepicker

Comment: use any other plugin like bootstrap for customizing